# I'm not able to change the page contents when i select combo-box options in php

Tags: php, combobox

```
<?php

// select box open tag
$selectBoxOpen =  "<select name='store_name'  >"; 
// select box close tag
$selectBoxClose =  "</select>";
// select box option tag
$selectBoxOption = ''; 

// connect mysql server
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
if (!$con) { 
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 

// select database
mysql_select_db("store", $con); 
// fire mysql query
$result = mysql_query("SELECT store_name FROM store_input");
// play with return result array 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
    $selectBoxOption .="<option value = '".$row['store_name']."'>".$row['store_name'] .  "</option>"; 
}

// create select box tag with mysql result
$selectBox =  $selectBoxOpen.$selectBoxOption.
$selectBoxClose; 

echo $selectBox; 

?>
```

this is my sample code, I have created combobox in php  with option values from database values
but i'm not able to change the page contents when i select options.

any answers

Answer (score 0):

Your code is lacking Javascript, which would be required for the outcome you are expecting. Seeing as you haven't really defined the complete outcome you expect, I will just show you what you need to update the url with the currently selected store:

`$selectBoxOpen =  "<select name='store_name' onchange=\"location.href=location.href+'?store='+this.value\"  >";`

I've added an onchange event ([read more about DOM events here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Events/Event_handlers?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web/Guide/DOM/Events/Event_handlers)) so that when you select a different value you are changing the location.

Now when you change the value of the select, your url should change to `scriptname.php?store=SomeStoreName`